# match query on elastic search with multiple or conditions

Tags: elasticsearch

I have three fields `status`,`type` and `search`. What I want is to search the data which contains `status` equals to `NEW` or `status` equals to `IN PROGRESS` and `type` is equal to `abc` or `type` equals to `xyz` and `search` contains( partial match ).

My call looks like below -

```
{
 "query": {
  "bool" : {
      "must" : [{
                "match": {
                "status": {
                    "query": "abc",
                    }
                }
                }, {
                    "match": {
                    "type": {
                        "query": "NEW",
                        }
                    }
                },{
                    "query_string": {
                        "query": "*abc*",    /* for partial search */
                        "fields": ["title", "name"]
                    }
                }]
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nest your boolqueries. I think what you are missing is this:

```
"bool": { "should": [ 
   { "match": { "status": "abc" } }, 
   { "match": { "status": "xyz" } } 
]}
```

This is a query which MUST match one of the should clauses as only should clauses are given.

EDIT to explain the differences:

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "bool": {
                  "should": [
                     {
                        "match": {
                           "status": "abc"
                        }
                     },
                     {
                        "match": {
                           "status": "xyz"
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "terms": {
                  "type": [
                     "NEW",
                     "IN_PROGRESS"
                  ]
               }
            },
            {
               "query_string": {
                  "query": "*abc*",
                  "fields": [
                     "title",
                     "name"
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

So you have a boolquery at top. Every of the 3 inner queries must be true.

1. The first is a nested boolquery which is true if status matches either abc or xyz.
2. The second is true if type matches **exactly** NEW or IN_PROGRESS - Note the difference here. The First one would also match ABC or aBc or potentially "abc XYZ" depending on your analyzer. You might want terms for both.
3. The third is what you had before.

Comment: How will I include `and type equals something` ?

Comment: Check the fullquery explanation